# Plotly table not returned in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to plot a table in a Jupyter notebook based on [this example](https://plot.ly/python/table/):

```
import plotly.offline as py #replaces import plotly.plotly as py
py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import plotly.graph_objs as go

print(plotly.__version__)

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90],
                       [95, 85, 75, 95]]))

data = [trace] 
py.iplot(data, filename = 'basic_table')
```

This returns for me just an empty graph instead of the desired table: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3VWo.png)

For plotting all other types of Plotly graphs I don't have any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Plotly example code is apparently outdated. There are two required changes:

- header values need to be a list of list

  ```
  values=[['A Scores'], ['B Scores']]
  ```
- A line color needs to be set

  ```
  line=dict(color='black'))
  ```

**Complete code**

```
import plotly.offline as py #replaces import plotly.plotly as py
py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=[['A Scores'], ['B Scores']],
                line=dict(color='black')
                ),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90],
                       [95, 85, 75, 95]],
               line=dict(color='black'))
)

data = [trace] 
py.iplot(data, filename = 'basic_table.html')
```

[image]